# The AngularJS directive ngClass is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

```html
<a href="#/main" class="bottom-nav-btn">
 <img ng-src="dist/images/toolbar1.png" alt="首页" class="nav-img" />
 <p class="nav-text" ng-class="{active: isActive==='main'}">首页</p>
 <p>{{ isActive === 'main' }}</p>
</a>
```

I am using this Angulars code.
Finally I find the expression {{ isActive === 'main' }} is  true,but the className 'active' is not updated

Comment: It still not worked. The varibale isActive, I define in the $rootScope, and change it by watch the event $stateChangeSuccess. May it has influence ?

Comment: Your code snippet is not working. Please see my below solution. If that doesn't work, please provide a working code snippet.

Comment: Try to use == comparation instead of === inside ng-class attribute.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/fLj0yq5n/):

```
<a href="#/main" class="bottom-nav-btn" ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">

angular.module('Joy', [])
.controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = 'main';
}]);
```

There must be something wrong with your code in other place. Most likely to be the `ng-controller`.